# React-Redux How to improve performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am using the react-redux for one of my app, The design is quite difficult and performance required is very high. its actually wyswyg builder.

We have been using the react from last 2 months, Then we moved to the react-redux for the separation of code and improve maitainance, code readability and the parent-child approach headache ofc.

So, I have an array which has quite complex structure

This is how my state look a like:

```
const initialState = {
  builder:{},
  CurrentElementName:"",
  CurrentSlideName:"",
  .......
}
```

As redux recommend to have less data in particular object as possible, I have another 8-9 reducer which are divided from the main state.

**My problem:** builder object is very complex which has almost 3-4 levels down, objects and arrays, this all are managed runtime.

So, on the `componentdidmount` my application will call the server get the data and fill the `builder:{}`

```
builder:{
   slidedata:[{index:0,controName:'button',....},{index:0,controName:'slide',....}],
   currentSlideName:'slide1',
   currentElementName:'button1'
}
```

This builder object is quite complex and depends on the user actions like drag and drop, changing the property, changing events, changing position this builder object is being changed by the reducer

```
 let clonedState= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
 //doing other operations
```

Every time some thing changes this object needs to perform certain complex operations, for ex, adding the new slide will do certain operations and add the slide to the current array called slidedata.

What is the best practice to fast this things up? am I doing something wrong?
I am not sure what is the wrong in this code, and as redux recommend I can not use the flat structure for this particular array as its managed run-time.

I am sure that component has the data which the component wants.

Is there any way to handle the big data? This iterations and changing the state is killing my performance.

Comment: For UI state (visual position of drag and drop elements in this case), I would not use Redux to handle that data. That's one of the few things I let the local component state handle. I'm not sure if it would be a performance hit or not in your case. Think of Redux sort of as a browser database. You wouldn't store ephemeral data like drag and drop position in a a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my current experience with React-Redux framework, [Re-select](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) and [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) make a perfect combination for your requirement.

Re-Select uses [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) technique on Javascript objects and have list of API's specifically dealing with these kind of large set of Javascript objects thus improving performance. Read the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/).

***Note: One should wisely read the documentation before using this setup to churn the best of these tools.***

You can either create your own boilerplate code using above libraries or use the one which i am currently using in my project.

https://www.reactboilerplate.com/

This boilerplate is specifically designed for performance. You can customize it based on your needs.

**Hope this helps!**